# Rasterize shapefile to a new gtiff file with gdal_rasterize utility,however,I cannot open the tif file?

Tags: gdal

Now I'm tring to rasterize a shapefile with a utility "gdal_rasterize" and want to generate a new gtiff file,but when I open the rasterized gtiff file,it prompts "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged,corrupted,or is too large.

.........................................................................................
.........................................................................................
Command Line:
gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ts 800 800 -l Countries02 "D:\Map Data\Countries02.shp" "D:\Result\Countries02.tif"

Map Data:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7EF4FFBCD523D8E0!431&authkey=!AKiLt1a0bpOGi7w

The output gdalinfo returns is as follow:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: d:\Result\World.tif
Size is 800, 800
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,83.623596191406250)
Pixel Size = (0.450000000000000,-0.217029495239258)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  83.6235962)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  83.6235962)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000)
Center      (   0.0000000,  -3.1882019)
Band 1 Block=800x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=87.551, StdDev=121.080
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=87.5514609375
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=121.07999102565
Band 2 Block=800x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
Band 3 Block=800x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by 'cannot open tif file'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three suggestions:

1. Try outputting to another format.  Maybe Jpeg or PNG.  These will likely work better with Windows Photo Viewer.
2. Download [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).  This will display your tiff quite well.
3. If neither work - could you run 'gdalinfo -stats Countries02.tif' and post the output.

Edit:

The output is float64.  This is likely the issue.  Try 'gdal_translate -ot Byte -scale Countries02.tif Countires02_scaled.tif'

I'm not sure why rasterize is creating 64-bit output, but not much reads 64-bit.  Also, -scale should not be necessary, but is precautionary.

Comment: Great Thanks! 
First,I'v used the JPEG and PNG to have a test,it says "not support",so i replace it with BMP and it works.
but I wish to get a GTIFF file,so I use the IrfanView to open the GTIFF file generated just now and it prompts "D:\Result\World.tif:Decode error!Invalid or unsupported TIF file"

Comment: What does gdalinfo return?

Comment: I'v pasted it on the content of the question

Comment: @EverFor Update in my answer.

Comment: Thanks!as you say,the issue is the default parameter  float64,I change the -ot parameter to byte and it works properly.gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ts 800 800 -ot BYTE -l Countries02 "D:\Map Data\Countries02.shp" "D:\Result\Countries02.tif"

Answer (score 1):

The tif file created by gdal is a geotiff, not a regular tiff image and is not necessarily readable by an image viewer. You need to open it in a gis like qgis